# date time now format

Tags: c#, sql

Hi I try to insert into DB date time and the Column is date  type what I need to do?
this  is the code

```
  string query = "INSERT INTO Feedback (user_Name, date_of_, Praise)  VALUES     ('"+TextBox1.Text+"',"+DateTime.Now+",'"+TextBox2.Text+"')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

Comment: Use SqlParameters, not a plain text

Comment: Wow, your code is completely open to a SQL injection attack..! Those 2 textboxes will enable any hacker to completely profile your web application and compromise your database. Use parameterized queries instead!

Answer (score 6):

I would advise against using time from the application server to insert values into the database. The most basic example how that can go wrong is that you could have two servers set to different time zones, that use the same database. What server's time is the right time?

Other thing is the neccessary transformation of a datetime to string when you are using inline SQL statements. If the application server and the database server are set to different cultures, you need to be extremely careful not to insert May 2nd (02.05), when you want to insert Feb 5th (02.05).

Sure, all these issues are avoidable, but why bother with them at all, when the RDBMS can do all that for us?

---

BTW, even if you don't want to use stored procedures, use parameters.
This code should be reformated like:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Feedback (user_Name, date_of_, Praise)  VALUES     (@username, getdate(), @praise)"; 

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.Text);
param.Value = text1;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param = new SqlParameter("@praise", SqlDbType.Text);
param.Value = text2;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

con.Open(); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

*Don't include the value directly in your SQL*.

Use a parameterized query instead. There's no point in messing around with string formatting when the database is quite capable of accepting a prepared statement with a `DateTime` parameter.

You should get in the habit of using query parameters for *all* values which can't be simply hard-coded into the SQL to start with. For example, your query is currently just blithely taking the contents of `TextBox1.Text` and inserting that into the SQL. That's a recipe for a SQL injection attack.

You should separate the *code* (the SQL) from the *data* (the values). Parameterized queries are the way to do that.

EDIT: Using a built-in function in the SQL is fine, of course, if you're happy to use the database's idea of "now" instead of your client's idea of "now". Work out which is more appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Why don't you use a TIMESTAMP column in your database ? Seems like overhead by inserting it through your code.</strike>

The following link provides more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(SQL.80).aspx

**edit:** Set the default value of your database column as [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx), and leave the column name out of your insert statement. The current date and time will be inserted by your database automatically. No problem with conversions anymore!

Comment: timestamp is a row versioning stamp-  nothing to do with date and time in SQL Server!

Comment: You are right, i mixed up with MySQL ! The idea i'm after is still valid though. Why inserting the "NOW" through code, when the DBMS knows that exact time as well..

Comment: This is a good idea if they don't do updates. But if updates include entering a datetime, then that should work.

Comment: The query explicitly says: "INSERT", so that's just making assumptions. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `DateTime.Now` with  `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Also, you should really parameterize your insert statement so that you cannot fall victim of a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

Comment: Parameterizing the query is a much better answer than just formatting the date appropriately. The OP simply shouldn't be including the data in the SQL statement to start with.

Comment: @linepogl - I understood from the question that he wants to put the date into the datebase, and not the time. I might of course be mistaken, but that should be easy to alter anyway. Regardless, he should parameterize the query anyway to make his application more robust as Jon Skeet has mentioned both in answers and comments.

Comment: yes, maybe you are right. But then why he used DateTime.Now and not DateTime.Today?

Comment: @linepogl - Honestly, it seemed he wasn't sure what he should use anyway, so I deducted as good as I could ;) I might of course be wrong also.

Answer (score 1):

There is a NOW() function in most SQL implementations.

Comment: If SQL Server - It is `getdate()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your DateTime to an Sql DateTime literal. The easiest way to do it is this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalisation.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Yet, especially for DateTime.Now, you may use some Sql function, such as `GetDate()` but that often depends on your database server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Date` property:

```
DataTime.Now.Date
```